# Quelle bonne requête pour avoir des analogies sur inspirassion.com

Tags: choix-de-mot, figure-de-style

Quel pattern utilisez-vous généralement pour identifier des comparaisons sur le moteur de recherche linguistique [inspirassion.com](https://inspirassion.com) ?

Answer (score 2):

Je travaille souvent en utilisant le modèle suivant :

> beau comme det nn ou aussi beau que det nn ou plus beau que det nn

[ESSAYER](https://inspirassion.com/fr/beau_comme_det_nn_ou_aussi_beau_que_det_nn_ou_plus_beau_que_det_nn)